# using keyboard with swtbot test

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, swtbot

I'm trying to run SWTbot test case that uses keyboard short-cuts. I could not find any reference for how to do it.

I'm pretty sure that should not be that difficult. I'll appreciate it if someone can write a small snippet.

Thanks,

Ziv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using the `pressShortcut()` methood?

For TreeItem:

```
final SWTBotTreeItem item = ...
item.select().pressShortcut(SWT.CTRL, 'F');
```

For TableItem:

```
final SWTBotTableItem item = ...
item.select().pressShortcut(SWT.CTRL, 'F');
```

For EclipseEditor

```
((SWTBotEclipseEditor)bot.activeEditor()).pressShortcut(SWT.CTRL, '1')
```

From Active Shell:

```
 bot.activeShell().pressShortcut(
        Keystrokes.CTRL, KeyStroke.getInstance("1"));
```

Answer (score 1):

For multiple modifiers keys you can use

```
item.select().pressShortcut(SWT.CTRL | SWT.ALT, 'F');
```